# How to check type of a subclass using the parent class in python?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, python-class

Let's say I have five classes represented like this:

```
class Operator:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Pow(Operator):
    pass

class Mul(Operator):
    pass

class Div(Operator):
    pass

class Add(Operator):
    pass

class Sub(Operator):
    pass
```

And an array of tokens some of them are numbers and the others are objects instantiated from the classes above {Pow, Mul, Div, Add, Sub}.

When I loop through the array, I want to be able to check for the type of token like this:

```
for token in tokens:
    if type(token) is Operator:
        # do something
```

Instead of doing this:

```
for token in tokens:
    if type(token) in [Pow, Mul, Div, Add, Sub]:
        # do something
```

I don't know if there is a good alternative for the second for loop.

(Any code refactoring is welcomed)

Answer (score 1):

Use method `isinstance(token, Operator)`

here is example

```
ar = Div()
if isinstance(ar, Operator):
    print("true")
```

Comment: is it possible to do something like ```token is Operator``` or ```token == Operator```?

Comment: Nope, command `type()` returns class name (like Div etc). You can mix it up using `issubclass` method in following way: `if issubclass(type(token), Operator)` but its ugly and does the same as `isinstance` do. 
If you need to have `==` or `is` the only way that comes to my mind is to do something like this `token.__class__.__base__ == Operator`. `_class__` method returns class (for example DIV), `__base__` returns parent class.

Answer (score 1):

```py
for token in tokens:
    if isinstance(token, Operator):
        # do something
```